# When does an iTunes link redirect to the iTunes app?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, redirect, url-scheme

When using the [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/de/) one gets an http-Link, which is pretty nice, since it work also on non-iOS-devices.

But when exactly does the redirect to the app happen, when I use it on a web page?

- Does Safari interrupt the request?
- or does the iTunes website answer to the request with a redirect to a store:// URL or something?

Comment: in iOS you would probably call it using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:YOUR_URL]`. In this case I'd assume that iOS itself scans the URL and decides what to do. If it's an *iTunes* link it would open iTunes/AppStore, otherwise it would open *Safari* that would try to load the page with address given in `YOUR_URL`

Comment: The Link Maker adds the attribute `target="itunes_store"`, which doesn't make any difference, at least not on iOS 7.

Comment: Redirecting to the generated http-URL also opens the app – nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparently it's the iTunes website which redirects based on **user agent string** – or a combination.

When opening the http-URL with a browser with the iPhone's user agent string I get a 301 return from the iTunes webserver to the App's URL scheme itmss://

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the link is built and if you have iTunes installed on your machine.

itms-apps links would work only on iOS devices same as macappstore that would work on a mac. Both would open directly the store without browser first.

If you are a Mac/iOS developer I think you should use [iLink](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ilink) which would figure out everything at run-time. This is the best solution for this complex issue.